# PHP Include , but only certain things

Tags: php, html

I am using php include to include a header and footer on my web pages. I have a navbar on all the headers and wanted to know if there is a way to have the header.phph not show up some of the nav items on certain pages. For example , people dont need to navigate to the contact page from the contact page so this nav item is not required. Hope someone can assist.

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
?>
<div class="third_bar"> 
    <div class="second_image"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form">
        <form action= "search.php" method="post"> 
            <input type="text" id="search_bar" placeholder="" value="Search" max length="30" autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();"/><input type="submit" id="search_button" value="Go!"/> 
        </form>  
    </div> 
</div> 

<?php 
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

**Header.php**

```
!doctype html>

<html>
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://www.com/favicon.png?v=2"/>
        <title>Wcom</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" href="style5.css"/>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function active() {
            var search_bar= document.getElementById('search_bar');
            if(search_bar.value == 'Search here') {
                search_bar.value=''
                search_bar.placeholder= 'Search here'
            }   
        }

        function inactive() {
            var search_bar= document.getElementById('search_bar');
            if(search_bar.value == '') {
                search_bar.value='Search  here'
                search_bar.placeholder= ''
            }   
        }
    </script>
    <div id="container"> 
        <div class="top_section"> 
            <div class="first_image"> 
                <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="nav_bar"> 
            <a href ="#"> About us</a> 
            <a href ="#"> Products & Pricing</a> 
            <a href ="contactpage.php"> Contact us</a> 
            <a href ="#"> login</a> 
       </div> 

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://"/>
        <title>?.com</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" href="style5.css"/>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function active() {
            var search_bar= document.getElementById('search_bar');
            if(search_bar.value == 'Search  here') {
                search_bar.value=''
                search_bar.placeholder= 'Search here'
            }   
        }

        function inactive() {
            var search_bar= document.getElementById('search_bar');
            if(search_bar.value == '') {
                search_bar.value='Search here'
                search_bar.placeholder= ''
            }   
        }
    </script>
    <div id="container"> 
        <div class="top_section"> 
            <div class="first_image"> 
                <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="nav_bar"> 
            <a href ="#"> About us</a> 
            <a href ="#"> Products & Pricing</a> 
            <a href ="contactpage.php"> Contact us</a> 
            <a href ="#"> login</a> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Kudos for working on a website for whisky!

Comment: Well someone has to, Its a hard life.

Comment: You should implement a logic inside the `header.php` code which decides what to show and what not. Altrnatively you _could_ hide things by using client side logic.

Comment: please start with a basics, just go to php.net and learn a bit before trying to code

Comment: You could put the contents of the file in a function with a parameter, which is used in an IF statement to decide whether to put the nav bar or not. Then require / include the file in the pages before calling a function using the parameter to display the navbar or not.

Comment: It can be unsettling and visually jarring having changes in navigation/main menu when moving between pages.  You could still print the menu item, but not have it as a link.  Or further strike through it, rather than remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to add conditional on your header.php page.

Say you have a variable at the beginning of each page which contains the page name, for instance on "contactpage.php":

```
$page = 'contact';
```

(note there is also a way to get the name of the current page on the `$_SERVER`superglobal variable)

Then you can conditionnally print your links in the navbar:

```
<div class="nav_bar"> 
<a href ="#"> About us</a> 
<a href ="#"> Products & Pricing</a> 
<?php if ($page !== 'contact') { ?>
<a href ="contactpage.php"> Contact us</a>
<?php } ?>
<a href ="#"> login</a>
```

Comment: OP: people dont need to navigate to the contact page from the contact page so this nav item is not required.

Comment: Thanks Pierre , appreciate the help. Only problem I have now is that the stylesheet for my header will overwrite the stylesheet for my index page. I have a stylesheet for my Index , Contact page etc. Only a two page site at the moment. Will I need to have just one style sheet for all pages.?

Comment: Its ok , I figured it out by leaving the stylesheet ref in the page I am using. Thanks for the help